# Have checked countless times and can't figure out where my error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, openweathermap

I've been playing around with the OpenWeatherMap API to learn to code and have run into a series of TypeError issues popping up in my console. My assumption is that my program is attempting to use data from the API before it is finished fetching, but I have set the fetch functions up to wait until receiving a response to add them to the corresponding state, and have tried many solutions. I have included my App.js code below (with the API Key committed):

```
function App() {
  // initialize location as UWS (no actual reason)
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("10024");

  // GeoCoder API data to feed into the main weather API
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState();

  // Main weather API data to feed to UI
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState();

  // GeoCoder API used for fetching latitude & longitude
  const geoCoder = `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/zip?zip=${location},US&appid=${API__KEY}`;

  // Main weather API used for feeding data to the UI (based on lat & lon from geoCoder API)
  const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${inputData.lat}&lon=${inputData.lon}&appid=${API__KEY}&units=imperial`;

  // Use user-submitted zip code to fetch latitude & longitude from geoCoder API
  const getInputData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(geoCoder);
    const jsonRes = await res.json();
    setInputData(jsonRes);
  };

  // Use Zip code from geoCoder API to fetch data from main weather API
  const getApiData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const jsonRes = await res.json();
    setApiData(jsonRes);
  };

  // Initialize website with data
  useEffect(() => {
    getInputData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Title />
      <Search
        location={location}
        setLocation={setLocation}
        getInputData={getInputData}
        getApiData={getApiData}
      />
      <Pinpoint apiData={apiData} />
      <ForecastPreview apiData={apiData} />
      <ForecastDetails apiData={apiData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Additional Context: The apiData state is passed to child components as props and used to render data on-screen from the data stored in apiData.

There are multiple errors in the console just like the one I included in my question's title, probably all stemming from the same issue.

Have been unable to figure this out for the last three hours. Any and all assistance is extremely appreciated.

Comment: You are building `url` before `inputData` has a value.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I thought running the getInputData() function inside the useEffect would make it render immediately. Is this incorrect?

Comment: `inputData` will not have a value until _after_ `getInputData()` causes the component to re-render (via `setInputData`)

Comment: You can either default it to something like `{ lat: null, long: null }` or use a conditional to check if it exists before using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try these steps to get the correct url generated with no errors:

1. Give `inputData` an initial value with correct data model
2. Give `url` a fallback value when `inputData` is not ready

The following live example will use a public API so there is no need for a key, and it should also work if switched to the project API.

Example: (over simplified live demo on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-data-test-udzz6t?file=/src/App.js))

`inputData` need correct data model for `url` to read its properties:

```
// GeoCoder API data to feed into the main weather API
const [inputData, setInputData] = useState({ lat: null, lon: null });
```

`url` need a fallback value when `inputData` is getting fetched but not ready yet (`null` is used in here but it can be anything, depending on how it will be used):

```
// Main weather API used for feeding data to the UI (based on lat & lon from geoCoder API)
const url =
  inputData?.lat && inputData?.lon
    ? `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${inputData.lat}&lon=${inputData.lon}&appid=API__KEY&units=imperial`
    : null;
```

Optional: the data fetching function can be created inside `useEffect` so it does not need to be added to the dependency array.

```
// Initialize website with data
useEffect(() => {
  const initInputData = async () => {
    if (!geoCoder) return;
    const res = await fetch(geoCoder);
    if (!res.ok) throw new Error("fetch failed");
    const jsonRes = await res.json();
    setInputData(jsonRes);
  };
  initInputData().catch((error) => console.error(error));
}, [geoCoder]);
```

There might be other issues needed to be addressed, but hopefully this could at least help generate the correct url without error.

Comment: Thank you! There is another error elsewhere but logically this makes complete sense to me

Answer (score 1):

Always set an `initial value` for state variables:

```js
const [inputData, setInputData] = useState({ lat: null, lon: null });
const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({})
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: the solution here was so simple, I feel like an idiot for not noticing it sooner. The comments were correct in that I needed a fallback. I set up the components that utilize the fetched data to be conditionally rendered when the desired state properties were truthy. I changed some things around for simplicity on the core document but the reason the solution works still holds true for both cases. If apiData.main and forecastData.list (this was created after posting the initial question) are both truthy, render components with fetched items, otherwise, render an empty string.

```
{apiData.main && forecastData.list ? (
    <>
      <Pinpoint apiData={apiData} />
      <ForecastPreview apiData={apiData} />
      <ForecastDetails
        apiData={apiData}
        forecastData={forecastData}
        getForecastData={getForecastData}
      />
    </>
  ) : (
    ""
  )}
```